# When connecting multiple UIPickerView,having error at titleForRow

Tags: swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I am creating advance search for car which will have `UIDatePicker`,`UIPickerView`,and `TableView` and I am having problem titleForRow.And i can see the data correctly if i hide one pickerview(score) and see another pickerview(results).But after i have opened second pickerview(results) and open another pickerview(score) without hiding the first one,when i try to scroll the score picker i have error at titleForRow which said "Array Index out of Range".So,if i am going to use multiple pickerview at one view controller?How do i connect them in right way?any help please?

Here is my design for 2picker and 1date picker,

[Pic 1](http://puu.sh/iJ1K5/33e8a7c20c.png)

As you see when i tapped one of static table cell,the picker appear and when i tapped again,the picker hide.

Here is my Advance Search Controller

[Pic 2](http://puu.sh/iJ1LF/b1d8de41b3.png)

This is the code i used to control my pickerview and static table cell

```
var pickerCollection : String = "Score"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    TegKeychain.set("currentView", value: "Advance")
    super.viewDidLoad()
    datePickerChanged()
    //self.scorePicker?.delegate = self

    scoreDetailLabel.text = scoresValues[0]
    resultDetailLabel.text = resultsValues[0]

    detailLabel.text = venue
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    TegKeychain.set("currentView", value: "Advance")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        toggleDatepicker()
    }
    if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0{
        pickerCollection = "Score"
        toggleScorePicker()
        scorePicker.reloadAllComponents()
    }
    if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 2{
        pickerCollection = "Result"
        toggleResultPicker()
        resultPicker.reloadAllComponents()
    }
    println("Section : \(indexPath.section)")
    println("Row : \(indexPath.row)")
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if datePickerHidden && indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        return 0
    }
    else if scorePickerHidden && indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 1{
        return 0
    }
    else if resultPickerHidden && indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 3{
        return 0
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerCollection == "Score"{
        return scoresValues.count
    }
    if pickerCollection == "Result"{
        return resultsValues.count
    }
    return 0
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    if pickerCollection == "Score"{
        return scoresValues[row]
    }
    if pickerCollection == "Result"{
        return resultsValues[row]
    }
    return ""
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerCollection == "Score"{
        scoreDetailLabel.text = scoresValues[row]
    }
    if pickerCollection == "Result"{
        resultDetailLabel.text = resultsValues[row]
    }
}

// I will not show Date Picker to make it simple.
```

Results Picker and Score Picker

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Scores ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var scorePickerHidden = true

var scores :[String:String] = ["":"All","S":"S","R":"R","RA":"RA","above 5":"Above 5","above 4":"Above 4","above 3":"Above 3","above 2":"Above 2","above 1":"Above 1","above 0":"Above 0"]
var scoresValues : [String] = ["All","S","R","RA","Above 5","Above 4","Above 3","Above 2","Above 1","Above 0"]

func toggleScorePicker() {

    scorePickerHidden = !scorePickerHidden

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Results ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var resultPickerHidden = true

var results :[String:String] = ["":"All","not yet":"Not Yet","unsold":"Unsold","sold by nego":"Sold by nego","others":"Others"]
var resultsValues : [String] = ["All","Not Yet","Unsold","Sold by nego","Others"]

func toggleResultPicker() {

    resultPickerHidden = !resultPickerHidden

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

Any help and suggestion please?I cant use only single picker because which don't meet my design.So,Is there any other way,i can connect my correct picker view when it appropriate static cell is tapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use multiple picker view, you have to use tag property at Attributes Inspector.So,Let say we have two `UIPickerView`.At the attributes inspector,set each UIPickerView with tag #1 and another with #2.And make sure they all connected to delegate and datasource of same view controller.

Then in your code,

```
var scoresValues = []
var resultsValues = []

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scoreValues = ["a","b",...]
    resultsValue = ["c","d",...]   
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView.tag == 1{
        return scoresValues.count
    }
    else{
        return resultsValues.count
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    if pickerView.tag == 1{
        return scoresValues[row]
    }
    else{
        return resultsValues[row]
    }
}
```

What i have shown was using 2 picker only.If u want to use more picker,u can handle them by using if/else or switch.